# .NET get custom configuration section as NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config, config

In my web.config , I break-out config sections into separate files :

```
<appSettings configSource="AppSettings.config" />
<mySettings configSource="MySettings.config" />
```

Then I use the ConfigurationManager to retrieve the settings :

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
```

NameValueCollection is handy because I can do :

```
var someSetting = appSettings["someSetting"];
```

I'd like to do the same for the custom config sections, but I can't figure out how to obtain a NameValueCollection :

```
Configuration configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ConfigurationSection section = configuration.GetSection("mySettings"); 
KeyValueConfigurationCollection mySettings = ((AppSettingsSection)section).Settings;
```

KeyValueConfigurationCollection also works for retrieving individual settings :

```
var mySetting = mySettings["mySetting"].Value
```

but I'd like to represent all of my config sections as the same type for purposes of handing off to generic processing routines.

How to obtain a NameValueCollection for a custom config section ?

Comment: Have you considered just building extension methods for both so the interface is *sytactically* the same?

Comment: But I need to pass the objects to a constructor that accepts a single parameter ...

Comment: The point is that those extension methods would be available from anywhere. So, you'd pass in either one and the extension methods would work.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this

```
NameValueCollection customSection 
 = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NAMEOFSECTION");
```

then use

`customSection["key"]` to retrieve the value

Just be careful as if the section is not available it will return `null`